# Recursive count of the number of comments to a post

Tags: mysql, sql

I am making a nested comment system, and I have the following table:

```
create table comments (
id int unsigned primary key auto_increment,
author_id int unsigned not null,
target_id int unsigned not null,
target_type set('post','comment') not null,
content varchar(2000) not null
);
```

Each comment may be targeting a post, or another comment, in which case it would be considered a reply. Is there a simple way to count the number of nested comments (comments + replies + replies to replies, etc.) to a given post (say, a post with id 1)?

I know that if I had a field called target_post_id and another called target_comment_id, instead of having target_id and target_type, it would be very easy to count all the comments for any given post, but I have reasons for trying to keep this table structure, and truth be told, I've never dealt with recursive queries before. Any help is appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: How many levels of comments can there be? Can I make a comment that targets a comment that targets a comment?

Comment: Hi GoldenNewby, I'll probably put a limit to the nesting level, but it will be higher than 2..

Comment: I think technically there is a way to do what you are trying to do. I expect the conventional answer will be no, but I think if you created a recursive mysql procedure you could do it. I don't think you'd want to though honestly. I think you could save yourself a lot of headache by just recording the post_id and comment_id, and making the comment_id null if this a reply to the post directly.

Comment: You are probably right, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is "no". The slightly longer answer is that you could keep a comment count on the overall post, and update it as you add/delete comments in your nested structure (which is denormalising, but not entirely unexpected in this kind of situation); or as you point out you can always point back to the post from every comment.